# PHP - Post syntax error

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

This is the code where i get a syntax error from.

```
<?php 
    if ($_POST['prestiti']){
        echo "<option value=".$_POST['prestiti']." 
        selected='selected'>.$_POST['prestiti']</option>";}    
    else{
        echo "<option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>";}
?>
```

ERROR ->;

```
unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or 
T_NUM_STRING in line
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: <?php 
     if ($_POST['prestiti']){
     echo "<option value=".$_POST['prestiti']." selected='selected'>.$_POST['prestiti']</option>";}
     else{
     echo "<option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>";}
           ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

```
if (isset($_POST['prestiti']) && $_POST['prestiti'] != ""){
   echo "<option value=".$_POST['prestiti']." selected='selected'>" . $_POST['prestiti'] ."</option>";
}else{
   echo "<option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have concatenation errors. Your errors is in line: `selected='selected'>.$_POST['prestiti']` you forgot a `"`

I have fixed these errors in code below

```
<?php 
     if ($_POST['prestiti']){
        echo "<option value=".$_POST['prestiti']." selected='selected'>".$_POST['prestiti']."</option>";}
     else{
        echo "<option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>";
    }
?>
```